# Node.js access the value of variable from another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

How do i get the value of myObject.myname, myObject.myage from the function getval? It returns undefined when i console.log it. Btw I'm using node js. Thanks.

```
    var post = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('Response: ' + data);

    var myObject = JSON.parse(data);

        console.log('----------------------------------------------');
        console.log(myObject.myname);
        console.log(myObject.myage);
        console.log('----------------------------------------------');
        });
    });

    function getVal() {
        //some code here
        console.log(myObject.myname);
        console.log(myObject.myage);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare `myObject` **outside** the anonymous function you pass to `request` (`var myObject`) instead of inside it. At present it is a local variable.
2. Call `getVal()` **after** the HTTP response has been received (otherwise it won't have been set yet). At present you aren't calling it at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a scope issue, can you try this instead?

```
var myObject = {};
var post = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Response: ' + data);

    myObject = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log('----------------------------------------------');
    console.log(myObject.myname);
    console.log(myObject.myage);
    console.log('----------------------------------------------');
    });
});

function getVal() {
    //some code here
    console.log(myObject.myname);
    console.log(myObject.myage);
}
```

Comment: By the way myObject contains myname, myage, and etc.

Comment: That should be no problem provided the object is declared in a scope which is accessible by getVal